# pasar valor de variables php a javascript de diferente archivo

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un código php (test.php) en el cual tengo un par de variables ($lati y $longi) cuyos valores quiero mandar a un .js (main.js) para usarlos en variables javascritp pero no lo he conseguido, después de algunos intentos decidí limpiar el código del main.js para solicitar su ayuda, espero puedan ayudarme.

**test.php**

```
<?php

header('Location: test.php?$longi='.$longi.'&lati='.$lati);

$coordenada = $_GET['valor'];

//Substraemos los grados y minutos de latitud
$latgrados = substr($coordenada, 18, 2);
$latminnmea = substr($coordenada, 20, 8);

//Divide los minutos entre 60
$latmnin = ($latminnmea/60);

$latitud = $latgrados+$latmnin;


$lati = substr($latitud, 0, 9);



//Substraemos los grados y minutos de longitud
$longrad  = substr($coordenada, 31, 3);
$lonminnmea = substr($coordenada, 34, 8);

//Divide los minutos entre 60
$longmin = ($lonminnmea/60);

// MUltiplica los grados por -1 para que salga negativo
$long = ($longrad);

$longitud = $long+$longmin;

$longi = substr($longitud, 0, 10);

$longi= $longi*-1;

echo $lati.", ".$longi;



$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","m3dina","motor");
mysqli_select_db($link, "motor");
$tildes = $link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //Para que se muestren las 
tildes
$result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tbl_coordenadas(FECHA,COORDENADA) 
values ('2017/11/10','".$coordenada."')");


?>
```

**main.js**

```
(document).ready(function($) {



    /*Google map canvas*/
    jQuery(document).ready(function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {

          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };



        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Aid',
                        icon: 'img/icon.png'
        });


    });





    /////////////////////////////
    // FORMA DE CONTACTO////////
    ////////////////////////////

    $("#contacto-form").validate({
        rules: {
            msg: {
                minlength: 20
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(){
            //Variables de los campos
            var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var telefono = $('#telefono').val();
            var comentario = $('#comentario').val();
            //var comentarios = $('#comentarios-contacto').val();
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function() {
                   /* $('#loadingFormContacto').show();
                    $('#buttonEnviarContacto').hide();*/
                },
                type: "post",
                url:'process.php',
                data:{
                    // Datos a enviar
                    nombre:nombre,
                    email:email,
                    telefono:telefono,
                    comentario:comentario
                    //comentarios:comentarios
                },
                success:function(){
                    $('#contacto-form')[0].reset();
                   /* $('#loadingFormContacto').hide();*/
                    $('#buttonEnviarContacto').show();
                    //alert('¡Mensaje enviado con éxito! Muchas gracias.');
                    $('#mensaje-enviado').show('slow');
                    // Luego lo ocultamos despuÃ©s de un tiempo.
                      setTimeout(function(){
                          $('#mensaje-enviado').hide('slow');
                      }, 5000);
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert('Hubo algún error en el envío del formulario.');
                    $('#loadingFormContacto').hide();
                    $('#buttonEnviarContacto').show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $.extend($.validator.messages, {
        required: "Favor de completar este campo.",
        email: "Favor de completar con un email válido",

    });;


});
```

Comment: AJAX desde main.js, mandas llamar test.php y que te regresa las variables en un arreglo o un json

Answer (score 1):

para hacer ese traspaso de datos, creo que la forma sería embeber el código del javascript en el archivo php, ya que el flujo de datos normalmente es de javascript a php no al revés.

```
    <?php

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function initialize() {
            var lati =  "<?php echo $lati ?>";
            var longi = "<?php echo $longi ?>" ;
            var mapOptions = {

              center: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
              zoom: 16,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };



            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi),
                            map: map,
                            title: 'Aid',
                            icon: 'img/icon.png'
            });


        });
       </script>
    ?>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de devolver información a una vista es con un return. No hagas lo que aconsejan más arriba es muy mala práctica combinar HTML con PHP.  Lo que necesitas es utilizar Ajax. Puedes utilizar la librería de axios. Es muy simple y limpia. Un ejemplo.

axios.pots(URL,{parámetros}).then(res=>{

Consolé.log(res.data);

},error =>{

Consolé.log(error);

});

En tu archivo PHP

$datos = (object) Array(

'dato1' => $var1,

'dato2' => $var2,

);

return json_encode($datos);